# Counting combinations of combinations that contain all underlying variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Imagine you have N letters, and therefore, $2^n$ cards which each contain some subset of those letters (for example, if you have 3 letters--A,B,C--there can only be 8 unique cards--$\emptyset$,A,B,C,AB,AC,BC,ABC).

A person draws a hand of some of those cards.

How many unique hands exist which contain all N letters? (There are $2^{(2^n)}$ unique hands, but some hands do not contain all letters: for example if $n=3$, the hand $\{A,AB\}$ does not contain $C$).

---

My first approach was to try and subtract out incomplete hands, but it telescopes pretty quickly for large $N$:

$HANDS(3) - 3*HANDS(2) + 3*HANDS(1)$

There are $HANDS(3)$ possible hands. Minus ${3 \choose 1} * HANDS(2)$  hands that could be constructed by removing one variable, plus ${3 \choose 2} * HANDS(1)$ that were double subtracted by the previous equation, etc... I believe this reduces to

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N}(-1)^n{N \choose N-n}HANDS(N-n)
$$

Or

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N}(-1)^n{N \choose N-n}(2^{2^{(N-n)}})
$$

Is there a more elegant solution? This feels like this can be simplified?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, so ask how many letters of each kind are there ?

Comment: Just one letter of each kind.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence [OEIS A000371](https://oeis.org/A000371) confirms your deduction.

There is no simpler formula there, therefore it is unlikely that it exists.